# What is the jacobian of an image lookup function?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, jacobians

I posted this question on Robotics Stack Exchange ([link](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/20336/what-is-the-jacobian-of-an-image-lookup-function)) but thought it could be relevant here as well.

I'm trying to solve a computer vision problem whereby I wish to use Levenberg–Marquardt non-linear optimization to solve the following equation:
$\left(\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{p}_{\min } \\ \mathbf{n}_{\min }\end{array}\right)=\underset{\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{n}}{\operatorname{Argmin}} \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(I_{k+1}\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}\right)-I_{k}\left(\mathbf{H}_{k+1}(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{n})\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}\right)\right)\right)^{2}}_{Q(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{n})}$

Whereby $\mathbf{x}_i$ stands for the $x,y$ coordinates of a provided image, $I$ is a function which represents the grayscale value of the $x,y$ coordinate in the image. For instance, $I(r,c)$ refers to the pixel value at row $r$ and column $c$ in the image, which has fixed dimension e.g $1024 \times 768$. $H$ is the function, or $3\times 3$ homography matrix constructed from $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{n}$,  converting vector $\mathbf{x}_i$ (coordinates $x_i, y_i$) into $\mathbf{x}_i'$ (coordinates $x_i', y_i')$.

Because gradient-related optimization requires the calculation of the Jacobian, can someone tell me **how do I formulate the partial deriviatives of the Image function I?** I understand that the size of the Jacobian is $n \times 2n$, where $n$ is the number of points to be used in the optimization.

The author of the paper did stated the following, but I did not quite get it.

> To numerically compute the optimization, the loss function is further modified by introducing a linearization of the image function $I$ as we do not know directly in which way the image function itself changes when the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ is modified. Thus, we use the first order term of its Taylor expansion.

Comment: Welcome to MO. As it is, little chances that anyone would be able to answer your question. Too many details are "hidden" under image processing jargon, which is not the usual language here. We do not know what $I$ and $H$ are explicitly, for example. Try rephrasing the question so that any analyst/applied mathematician can read it

Comment: thank you @AmirSagiv, I have added more details about I and H .

Comment: @goh it would help if you a) gave a link to the paper and b) typed out equations, rather than included images. I have only managed to do the second of these, Google doesn't return hits that match the quoted text exactly. I corrected an ungrammatical typo to read "I understand that the size of the Jacobian is $n\times 2n$", but I'm not 100% confident that's what you meant; it's the only thing that makes sense to me in the context, but I don't know what you know about this stuff.

Comment: I also added a link to the other question, and you should include a link to here in your Robotics.SE question.